# Push a portrait view when device is in landscape or vice-versa in iOS6-7

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I've looked around and tried different things but none of them seem to work well.

I want to be able to push a view which is supposed to be portrait only when the device is currently orientated in landscape and the other way around.

I've setup shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation properly. They work when the device is manually rotated. However fails if the device isn't rotated. Once rotated, they work as expected. It's only the initial presentation that doesn't work.

Is there a way to force the OS to make calls to the above methods? I tried "present modal view controller hack". This worked fine on 6.0 but doesn't do well on iOS 7.0.

So, is there any way to get this to work? Or do you guys suppose asking the user to rotate the device before pushing the view to be a better solution?

Looking forward to your replies. Do keep in mind, I need support for both iOS 6 & 7.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

If it's working properly after the rotates, perhaps all it will take is to run part of your code in the `viewDidLoad`.

Never ask the user to rotate (or do anything for that matter) to get something working properly.  It would give a very negative user experience, in my mind at least.  All it takes is a little more time and effort to get it working properly. :)